# Create footer with two different colors

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a footer according to a design I received ...

The background color on the left is different from the right one:

[image: Footer]

I have the following markup:

```
<div class"wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    The Text here should no go over the logo
  </div>
</div>
```

My idea is Content DIV to have the logo as background image aligned left and no repeat.

But then I don't know how to create the different color on left and right ...

And I am not sure if I can control the height so that everything aligns.

The content div is centered and has the orange border on the image ...

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://codepen.io/nicknameless/pen/cblzB/

I've used CSS3 and no additional markup. This should work for you. It could be cleaned up I think, this is just a quick overview to get you started.

The HTML you provided

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    The Text here should no go over the logo
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  background: #850000;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  top: calc( 100px - 40px );
}
div.wrapper:before {
  background: transparent url('http://placehold.it/100x100') no-repeat 0 0;
  content: " ";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10%;
}
div.content {
  left: calc( 10% + 100px );
  padding-left: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #C70000;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc( 100% - ( 10% + 100px ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's was really a pain in the ass, I recommend to take the inner rectangle as a picture, but if you really want it in CSS, here it's: http://jsfiddle.net/B97ym/

HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class="content">The Text</div>
<div class='border'>
    <div class='border2'></div>
    <div class='border3'></div>
    <div class='logodiv'>
        <div class='rectangle'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #9c9e9f 40%, #000000 40%);
}

.content{
    margin: 0 0 0 50%;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.border{
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    background: #FF0000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 33.7%;
    top: -55%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #000000 62%, #9c9e9f 62%);
}

.border2{
    width: 0.8em;
    height: 4em;
    background: #9c9e9f;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80%;
}

.border3{
    width: 0.8em;
    height: 0.85em;
    background: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80%;
    top: 80%;
}

.logodiv {
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%;
    left: 18%;
}

.rectangle{
    width: 2.1em;
    height: 2.1em;
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    top: -42%;
    left: -42%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

**Hope it's will be helpful to someone (:**

Comment: What do you mean the inner rectangle as an image? I do not mind to do that ... I prefer simple code even if I need to use a larger image ...

Comment: Okay, so the code is much simpler: (http://jsfiddle.net/LK399/). The image is a simple rectangle, i cut her from your pic: (http://s16.postimg.org/y6bfy058x/Untitled.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS background-image on the wrapper layer that contains the entire logo, bars an all. Add enough margin-left on the inner layer to shove the text beyond the logo.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div with two div's inside with 50% width for left and right and fixed height. Make sure you overflow the logo.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4qu2f/) will give you a place to start.

CSS

```
.holder {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    position: relative;
}
.leftdiv {
    width: 40%;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
.rightdiv {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}
.logodiv {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 157px;
    top: -42px;
    background-color: white;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-left: 20px solid blue;
    border-right: 20px solid red;
    border-top: 20px solid red;
    border-bottom: 20px solid blue;
}
.whiteout {
    background-color: white;
    width: 30px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    left: 183px;
}
```